# Converting json object with variable attributes into xml array

Tags: json, xml, api

The Api response is  {"Content":{"634331":["Product could not be found"],"634332":["Product could not be found"],"etc…

and I am having trouble to catch the values after content into xml :

```
  <Content>

        <__634331>Product could not be found</__634331>

        <__634332>Product could not be found</__634332>

        <__123104398>Product could not be found</__123104398>
```

The values are being interpreted as field names.

Is there a way to convert json object into xml array looking like:

```
<Content>

<res>
<key>634331</key>
<value>Product could not be found</value>

</res>

<res>
<key>634332</key>
<value>Product could not be found</value>

</res>
```

Comment: Please, include the code that does the conversion at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common in JSON for keys in a map (or "object") to represent data values rather than property names. Unfortunately this doesn't map at all well to XML, where the equivalent would usually be a structure like

```
<data key="__634331" value="Product could not be found"/>
```

No automatic converter is going to be able to recognise that this kind of conversion is appropriate.

My recommendation would be to do a custom conversion using XSLT 3.0 template rules. I would need to see more detail of your JSON and required XML to advise in more detail.

Comment: This is example of a json:
{"Content":{"634331":["Product could not be found"],"634332":["Product could not be found"],"123104398":["Product could not be found"],"123104401":["Product could not be found"],"123104403":["Product could not be found"],"123104404":["Product could not be found"]},"StatusCode":200,"LogId":null,"Success":true,"Message":"Updates processed, see 'Content' for warnings","ValidationErrors":{}}

I'd like to covert it into XML, However, working with variable fieldnames is not an option for my system